# Dropwizard custom validation annotation not working

Tags: java, validation, jersey, dropwizard

I'm trying to apply multiple common annotations at once with a custom validation annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Length(max=25, min=1, message="invalid length")
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 25})")
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

And using it in my model classes like this:

```
@MyAnnotation
public String firstName;
```

None of these validation are working, but they work as expected when used in the model class itself.  I also tried registering MyAnnotation in the applications run method, and that didn't work either.

`environment.jersey().register(MyAnnotation.class);`

What else do I need to do in order to use custom validations?

Comment: Answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837497/how-do-i-use-a-custom-validator-with-dropwizard/37863750#37863750

Answer (score 0):

Either annotate the String directly:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 25})")
@NotNull
@Length(max=25, min=1, message="invalid length")
public String firstName;
```

Or create a validator, something like:

```
class MyAnnotatationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, String>{
  @Override
  public void initialize(MyAnnotation a){}
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidationContext c) {
    return s != null && (s.length() > 0 && s.length() < 26) && s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 25})";  
  }
}
```

And have

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyAnnotatationValidator.class)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  String message() default = "{MyAnnotation}";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload> payload() deafult {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition)

> A constraint definition may have attributes that are specified at the time the constraint is applied to a JavaBean. The properties are mapped as annotation elements. The annotation element names message, groups and payload are considered reserved names; annotation elements starting with valid are not allowed; a constraint may use any other element name for its attributes.

So you must add message, groups and payload attributes to your `@MyAnnotation`.
A composition is done by annotating the composed constraint, example:

```
@Length(max=25, min=1, message="invalid length")
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 25})")
@Documented
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String message() default "My annotation message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the validations are not being applied for some reason.

Comment: Could you share more details about your code? 
Are you trying to validate a POST body like: 
    @POST
    public void validPost(@Valid MyBean mybean) {}

Or in a JPA layer ?