# Custom Hibernate validator not working in a DropWizard application

Tags: java, dropwizard, hibernate-validator

I am trying to add a custom validator to my REST method. The issue is the validator is not getting invoked.

I am using the same code as mentioned in the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837497/how-do-i-use-a-custom-validator-with-dropwizard). I have the CustomValidation annotation, the CustomValidator class implementing ConstraintValidator. The only difference is my resource method is POST with signature:

```
@POST
public Result createObject(@Valid @CustomValidation MyObject myObject){
}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

--EDIT - adding code

CustomValidation

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomValidator.class})
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomValidation {


      String message() default "Invalid upload data";

      Class<?>[] groups() default {};
      Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

CustomValidator.java

```
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidation, MyObject> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomValidation constraintAnnotation) {
         System.out.println("Initializing validator");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyObject value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {    
        System.out.println("Validation called");    
        return false;
    }

}
```

Rest resource:

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyObjectService extends BaseRestService{

    @POST
    public Result createObject(@Valid @CustomValidation MyObject myObject){
    }

}
```

I have verified that the hibernate validator jar is being included as a dependency.

Comment: The original question also is using @POST. So update your question with your exact code.

Comment: I was referring to the code in the accepted answer which is what I am trying to get working. FWIW I added the annotation on a GET method too, but the validator is not being invoked.

Comment: Please provide [minimum complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your implementation of the problem.

Comment: `@ApiParam` seems missing, and `@Valid` will validate your `MyObject`, the custom validator should be on the `MyObject` Class

Comment: @Ôrel `@ApiParam` is [Swagger annotation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiparam). It is not related at all. I expect the problem to be that the `CustomValidator` is defined for a `String` object, not for the `MyObject`. But I can't be sure until the exact code is posted. That's why I asked for the complete code.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have added the code I am using. Let me know if I can provide more detail.

Comment: @jbtx_0808: I can confirm that the example from the other question is working with `POST` and Dropwizard 1.0.0. Also note that you have two differences from the given example: your custom annotation is defined only for `PARAMETER` and your Resource class is extending from some base class. I've checked the first and it is working for the given scenario. You should try to remove the extending of the base class and see what will happen.

Comment: `vagrant@tfb-all:~/dropwizard-static$ curl -d @validate http://localhost:8080/validate --header "Content-Type:application/json"
isValid() CustomValidator called
{"errors":["The request body Invalid upload"]}` My message in the annotation is "Invalid upload" instead of "Invalid upload data" and `isValid() CustomValidator called` is printed in the `CustomValidator.isValid()` method.

Comment: This is my toy project where this is working: https://gitlab.com/zloster/dropwizard-static